# Can I use LEDs in parallel with an LED driver?

Tags: led-driver

I'm using an LED driver to drive a few LEDs in parallel but I'm confused by the datasheet. The component is a [PAM2863](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/PAM2863.pdf). In the description, you can read "designed for driving single or multiple series connected LEDs", which would mean that the LEDs must be in series, but in the typical applications circuit you can see the circuit driving a few LEDs in parallel.

Is there any problem to use a parallel circuit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a 2A switching regulator, whereas typically LEDs for lighting are on the order of ten to hundreds of milliamps per die. So yes, they're expecting you to parallel diodes. Outside of a relatively few, expensive high current diodes that driver will be overkill for series only LEDs.

This might seem strange, but over the years as LED manufacturing has improved bins have become much tighter even on typical products. Most manufacturers will now provide you with tightly matched forward voltages on very inexpensive parts. For example, I just picked a random 65mA LED on digikey that cost 6 cents in units of one (with digikey markup). The manufacturer provided binning 100mV wide by default.  In this configuration if you run at the typical current and paired up the min and max Vf for that bin in parallel with zero resistance, you'll still be well under the maximum current. In reality you'd put a few diodes in series before running them in parallel, and the series combination will introduce resistance while individual Vf would tend to average out across the string, so current would be even better balanced.  It is mainly when you go to eBay or Amazon as your LED supplier that putting diodes in parallel becomes dangerous.

Answer (score 3):

LEDs in series will ALWAYS work, as the current through them is identical. You set a drive current, and that's what you get in each LED. You can set the current quite aggressively high, and know that it's not going to exceed that in each LED. If there's a failed short in the string, that LED won't light, and the string voltage will be lower, if you're using a proper current source to drive them. If there's a failed open, the whole string won't light. You'll have to troubleshoot it, but nothing will burn.

LEDs in parallel MAY work, if they're from the same batch, staying at the same temperature. The current will still divide somewhat unequally between the LEDs even with these precautions, due to slight threshhold voltage variations in them, and very unequally if you don't take those precautions. You have to set the supply current lower than the maximum to allow for this difference in current division. A failed short LED will hog the entire supply current, and might smoke or unsolder itself. A failed open LED will allow all the other LEDs to draw more current than you had intended.